# Spinner android custom "Prompt"

Tags: android, spinner, android-actionbar

I'd like to use a spinner in DropDownMod as a Menu in the action bar

I need the spinner shows a fixed prompt even if it has an item selected, without showing which element has been selected.

Even more... I need that this prompt is a view like a layout and not just a text string.

Any ideas?